# Remove Logging with Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, logcat

I am trying to remove the log statements without success. Other SO answers to the same question refer to Eclipse or to an old Android Studio IDE (Intellij).

**build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
...
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

I can still see the log statements after getting the source code from the signed *app-release.apk*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

a change in the **build.gradle**, replacing the default *proguard-android.txt* with *proguard-android-optimize.txt* did the trick.

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
...
```

Note: the default proguard setting in gradle is *proguard-android.txt*

Comment: This really saved my day! This is actually mentioned here (indirectly): https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-code

Comment: after using proguard-android-optimize.txt i am getting error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Form-encoded method must contain at least one @Field.

Comment: What was your change?? This code looks exactly the same as the question....

Comment: @JohnathanLogan 'proguard-android.txt' to 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'