# Proguard can not remove log cat in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, proguard

The below code is my config for remove `Logcat` in debug mode using `Proguard` follow some post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218772/removing-log-call-using-proguard), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553146/disable-logcat-output-completely-in-release-android-app), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214623/remove-logging-with-proguard) but it not work. My `Logcat` is still display.
What do I do wrong here?
Another question is I see some person suggest another way for remove log is create a custom LogcatUtils class like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4592958/5381331), or use [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) so I wonder if `Proguard` can remove `Logcat` or not ?
I still prefer remove Logcat completely because I think it may reduce the APK size.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

My **build.grade**

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

**Activity code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Log.d("TAG", "hehe");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested it on emulator with Build Variant = debug
**DEMO PROJECT**: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_poNaia6t8kSTRMV2cxUjlaSDA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `debuggable` configuration

```
debug {
  minifyEnabled true
  debuggable false //add this to remove logcat
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Comment: thank you. but I have test and Logcat still display :(. if you want to see the demo project, please check https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_poNaia6t8kSTRMV2cxUjlaSDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you have zipped the project with build folder which makes the file too big to download. can u just post the `build.gradle` file alone

Comment: it just 28Mbs. my demo project is really simple don't contains any specific part. if you can not download you can create one then test. I think you will face the problem like me

Comment: Just take it as a suggestion, whenever you zip an android project make sure you delete the `build` folders

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_poNaia6t8kSTRMV2cxUjlaSDA/view?usp=sharing thank you for you suggestion. I have delete build update the project

Comment: I have tested your project. It works as expected. My guess is you are creating a release build and testing that. create a debug build by pressing `shift+F10` in Androidstudio

Comment: it's really strange, sometime I see the logcat display and sometime I don't see it. I will try to verify then notify you later. thank you so much for your help